# Click on push notification doesn't open new url every time

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to open a new URL every time while clicking on the notification in javascript. 
with the below code I can able to receive the push notification. I can redirect to the URL which I send the first time. But the second time I can not redirect to the new URL instead, I redirect to the URL which i previously passed. Here is my code please help me regarding same.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging()
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message', payload.data);
    const notification = payload.data;
    const notificationTitle = notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: notification.message,
        icon: notification.icon || "/images/icon.png"
    };
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
        event.notification.close();
        event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(notification.url));
    });
    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution of it
i have create global variable and every time `setBackgroundMessageHandler` function calls i have update it

```
var myUrl = "";
const messaging = firebase.messaging()
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message', payload.data);
    const notification = payload.data;
    const notificationTitle = notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: notification.message,
        icon: notification.icon || "/images/icon.png"
    };
    myUrl = notification.url;
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
        event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(myUrl));
        event.notification.close();
    });
    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: can you help me please at my case with firebase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73427810/click-on-push-notification-not-open-new-url-just-focus-same-domain-tap